# Uploading a larg document to CMIS-based servers using opencmis

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, documentum, cmis

I want to upload a large file maybe `500MB`. on `CMIS` based servers. `Alfresco`,  `Documentum` and `Microsoft SharePoint`

Would I face problems ?, if yes, are there suggestion to handle that ?

### edit

I am still searching to build a `java` client using `opencmis`. I think I will face such problem and I want to know is there a possible handling using this lib

Comment: What method are you going to use to upload? Via a dedicated CMIS client or your own? And if the former, which one?

Comment: I am still searching to build a java client using opencmis. I thnik I will face such problem and I want to know is there a possible handling using this lib

Comment: The OpenCMIS client library has been tested with documents up to 2GB. There is no technical limitation to support even larger documents.

Comment: @FlorianMüller that looks like an answer rather than a comment, you might want to promote it to one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) to upload your content it is the most advanced CMIS client implementation.

- As stated by Florian Müller (Apache Chemistry Chair, CMIS Committee
  Member) OpenCMIS is tested to handle 2GB, so your 500MB documents are
  supported without problems.
- There are two bindings for CMIS which are REST/ATOM and SOAP
  Webservices. There might be differences in performance between the
  two, with SOAP most likely being slower. This is something you should
  test if performance is an issue.
- Use the OpenCMIS Workbench Desktop Client to easily try out the
  transfer to your target repositories. This is the best way the see
  how your content repositories work together with OpenCMIS.